# Unable to append a rect to a SVG using d3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG inside a div in the html body and I am using d3 to append a "rect" to this SVG, but the rect is not getting generated.

```
<script>
    //Select the SVG Container
      var svgContainer = d3.select("#svg_container");
      //Draw the Rectangle
      var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect").attr("x", 10).attr("y", 10).attr("width", 50).attr("height", 100);
```

```
<svg id="svg_container" width="1000px" height="800px"</svg>
```

Here is a plunkr added - https://embed.plnkr.co/aNW8NtiRfS6FkSQMHtkB/

Any help in generating the "rect" would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the script.js after loading your libraries.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8qxmu5KpPZroGhB1odGK?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="MyApp">
      <div id="container" ng-controller="driversController">
            <div id="ElementPane" class="container">    
                <svg id="svg_container" width="1000px" height="800px"></svg>
            </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```